# php ssh2_tunnel Unable to request a channel from remote host

Tags: php, ssh, proxy

That's my code

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("88.76.192.38", 22);
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, "admin", "1234"))
{
    if ($tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '85.90.214.153', 80)) {
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "Tunnel creation failed.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "failed!";
}
die();
```

I have tried different hosts and ports for function ssh2_tunnel, now there passed my public IP. But every time I get an error:

> Warning: ssh2_tunnel(): Unable to request a channel from remote host

Comment: tell me please, which params I should pass into function ssh2_tunnel ? I think the problem is somewhere in this function, may be wrong host or port. Which right data ?

Comment: Have you googled for PHP bugs? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57427 or https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58893 ? This could either be a problem with multiple consecutive calls or something else. My clients are experiencing these issues, too, but we never managed actually find a root cause nor a way to reproduce. It would be really nice if you could provide more information on your infrastructure.